# Bit interleaving optimized for Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Granted, optimizing bit twiddling in Ruby is a bit of a mismatch to begin with. That aside, I'm looking for a snippet or a gem that can interleave two arbitrary integer coords optimized as best can be for MRI (1.9) or a native gem.

Some approaches in C are: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious

As an example or starting point, here's "Interleave bits the obvious way" in Ruby, somewhat uglified to keep it from creating temp arrays (which increase the runtime by about 2X per array) and with a binary length method inlined for a further 6% decrease (If you know neither input is ever zero, you can omit that check for a few percent more..)

```
def interleave(y)
  z = 0
  bl = self > 0 ? Math.log2(self) : 1
  ybl = y > 0 ? Math.log2(y) : 1
  ((((bl <=> ybl) == -1) ? ybl : bl).floor + 1).times{|i| z |= (self & 1 << i) << i | (y & 1 << i) << (i + 1)}
  return z
end
```

Results from a 2.66Ghz i5 with 1.9.2p180:

```
x = y = 0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111
Benchmark.bm{|bm| bm.report{1000000.times{x.interleave(y)}}}

     user     system      total        real
18.360000   0.010000  18.370000 ( 18.356196)
```

Surely there's a better way?

---

#### Update

I included the zero fix from @Wayne Conrad, albeit far uglier than his and only marginally faster. Also moved the floor and + 1 so as to be executed once instead of twice per.

Here is a [Gist of this with matching de-interleave](https://gist.github.com/846454).

Comment: There's a bug if either of the arguments is zero.  I'll add the fix to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, corrected that in the Q and Gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick & cheesy implementation to get you going until a good one comes along:

```
def mortanize(x, y)
  xs, ys = [x, y].map do |n|
    n.to_s(2)
  end
  nbits = [xs, ys].map(&:size).max
  xs, ys = [xs, ys].map do |n|
    ('0' * (nbits - n.size) + n).chars
  end
  ys.zip(xs).join.to_i(2)
end
```

As you might expect, it's no speed deamon.  On my box, with MRI 1.8.7, it computes about 35,000 16-bit results per second.  Yours computes 68,000 16-bit results per second.  Or, see the next algorithm for 256,000 16-bit results per second.

---

If you're willing to trade a little memory and startup time for speed, then:

```
def base_mortanize(x, y)
  xs, ys = [x, y].map do |n|
    n.to_s(2)
  end
  nbits = [xs, ys].map(&:size).max
  xs, ys = [xs, ys].map do |n|
    ('0' * (nbits - n.size) + n).chars
  end
  ys.zip(xs).join.to_i(2)
end

MORTON_TABLE_X = 256.times.map do |x|
  base_mortanize(x, 0)
end

MORTON_TABLE_Y = 256.times.map do |y|
  base_mortanize(0, y)
end

def mortanize(x, y)
  z = []
  while (x > 0 || y > 0)
    z << (MORTON_TABLE_X[x & 0xff] | MORTON_TABLE_Y[y & 0xff])
    x >>= 8
    y >>= 8
  end
  z.reverse.inject(0) do |result, word|
    result << 16 | word
  end
end
```

This one computes 256,000 16-bit results per second.

---

There's a bug in your answer if either argument is zero.  Here's one possible fix for it.  First define this function:

```
def bit_size(x)
  return 1 if x == 0
  Math.log2(x).floor + 1
end
```

And then, inside `interleave`, replace:

```
z, bl, ybl = 0, (Math.log2(self)).floor + 1, (Math.log2(y)).floor + 1
```

with:

```
z = 0
bl = bit_size(x)
ybl = bit_size(y)
```

---

Here is the rspec test case I used:

```
describe "mortanize" do
  it "should interleave integers" do
    mortanize(0, 0).should eql 0
    mortanize(0, 1).should eql 2
    mortanize(1, 0).should eql 1
    mortanize(0xf, 0x3).should eql 0x5f
    mortanize(0x3, 0xf).should eql 0xaf
    mortanize(0xf, 0x0).should eql 0x55
    mortanize(0x0, 0xf).should eql 0xaa
    mortanize(0x3, 0xc).should eql 0xa5
    mortanize(0xf, 0xf).should eql 0xff
    mortanize(0x1234, 0x4321).should eql 0x210e0d12
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, a very readable impl using a bunch of Ruby stuff; I like it. If you're curious about comparison with the sample I just added to the question, the BM for this: `user 185.240000 system 0.160000 total 185.400000 real (185.204548)`

Comment: Good point on the fix for my approach—you ought to make your version of mine a separate answer that can be accepted (tip, inline the bit_size method and call floor + 1 only once after the larger size is found for another speed boost.)

Comment: @Yuri, I think you ought to add it--it's your answer, after all!  I don't mind losing the checkmark; besides, that degree of optimization, where the intent of the code begins to get buried, makes me queezy.  It's probably time to write C (per Chuba's answer) if you need it optimized that much.

Comment: @Wayne: heh heh, I wonder if Meta has answer for when everyone says "no you take the credit."  Maybe I'll just update the Q. I've thought about C, unfortunately my C-chops don't extend to efficiently dealing with inputs that, coming from Ruby, may well be 7 bits or 300 bits wide.

Comment: @Yuri, Answer new and improved.  Please see above.

Comment: @Wayne. Now that's awesome (the latest, middle code), clean and yet a bit faster than my utterly illegible approach. But, still trying to wrap my head around if/where the limits would be (e.g., can it handle 300bit ints?) and why my interleaving and this mortanize give completely different results.

Comment: @Yuri, I intend for that code to handle any number of bits.  I'll append my rspec test cases to the answer.  Does your code pass those tests?

Comment: @Wayne, nice specs, very helpful and both my illegible and your #mortanize approaches pass them. I think they differ in their handling of numbers with different bit sizes, i.e., `0b1111_1111.interleave(0b1111).should == 0b101_0101_1111_1111`.

Comment: @Yuri, Your current code passes that test, as does mine.  Thank you for reminding me that Ruby has a binary literal format.  I try to learn all the time, but there seems to be room for only so much stuff in my noggin...  I'm always losing stuff I already knew!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution, benchmarked about 50% faster than the accepted one, and for 16-bit integers (where the first one only does 8-bit):

```
Magic = [0x55555555, 0x33333333, 0x0F0F0F0F, 0x00FF00FF]

# Interleave lower 16 bits of x and y, so the bits of x
# are in the even positions and bits from y in the odd;
# z gets the resulting 32-bit Morton Number.  
# x and y must initially be less than 65536.
# Rubyfied from http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html
def _interleave_bits_16b(x,y)
  x = (x | (x << 8)) & Magic[3]
  x = (x | (x << 4)) & Magic[2]
  x = (x | (x << 2)) & Magic[1]
  x = (x | (x << 1)) & Magic[0]
  y = (y | (y << 8)) & Magic[3]
  y = (y | (y << 4)) & Magic[2]
  y = (y | (y << 2)) & Magic[1]
  y = (y | (y << 1)) & Magic[0]
  z = x | (y << 1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an implementation already in C, you can use [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi), otherwise you can write it directly with the help of [RubyInline](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/)